# Python execute JavaScript on Website

Tags: javascript, python

I need to execute a JavaScript on a website, to perform a action.
In fact, to buy something on Steam.
Example: 
I visit http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/238460/Rammy with my Webbrowser. 
At the bottom of the page there are some buttons with Javascript on it.
For example they're bound to:
`javascript:BuyMarketListing('listing',%20'428187075130762395',%20238460,%20'2',%20'41998256')`

How can I execute these Script with Python?

Comment: Why would you want to buy things from a python script?! It would be extremely hard to get past the payment info and security that Steam has, and I for one am very happy that that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mozrunner`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mozrunner/6.7) to run Firefox from python, then have it open a tab and return some results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this legitimately for your own use, and not as some way to force someone else's browser to submit a purchase without their approval... have you tried just... well... clicking the button?

If you have some legitimate reason to be able to do this, well then Python isn't going to help you. Outputting JavaScript on your own browser to call that "BuyMarketListing" function won't work because you'd be trying to run a cross-browser script, and that's not allowed (unless you program it into a browser plugin or something and convince users to install it)... for good reason.

Alternatively, you could find out (if you dig around in Firebug or something) what URL the function is ultimately sending a POST/GET request to, but chances are there are protections in place to prevent that (also for good reason).